# Is there a way to toggle Dark Mode on/off for individual apps in macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, macos-darkmode

Is there a way in Terminal to toggle Dark Mode On/Off for an individual app without affecting the rest of the environment?

I use calendar on my Mac, and the appearance is dreadful. The rest of the apps look great in Dark Mode. I want to disable it JUST for that one app.

Comment: An identical question in AskDifferent, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/can-i-turn-to-dark-mode-only-for-specific-apps-in-macos-mojave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `Terminal`, run this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance true
```

To revert the change:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance false
```

Comment: To revert, you should do `defaults delete com.apple.iCal NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance`.

Comment: To find the Bundle Identifier of an app, for example Mail.app, use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :CFBundleIdentifier" /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Info.plist`

Comment: Bundle Identifier can also be looked up with: `osascript -e 'id of app "<App-Name>"'`

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.mail NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance true` doesn't work at least after MacOS 11.2.1. But there is a setting in viewing of `Mail` preference to turn off dark mode for messages, in case someone thinks it's hard to read with a black background as well.