# toggle switching dark mode programmatically macOS Mojave

Tags: macos-sierra, macos-mojave

Currently, I did not find a way of toggle macOS Mojave's dark mode programmatically.

An Apple Script [here](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/change-light-dark-mode-applescript-app/) works but it is very difficult to be embedded in Sandbox apps. Yes, actually you can do like [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/).

The purpose for this request would be a one-click user switching within the app. It would be very convenient for them in some apps like my [FocalPoint](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/Single/id882677998).

There is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562383/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-dark-mode-on-off-for-individual-apps-in-macos-mojave) related question & solution but it is quite different and not what I need.