# How to Disable Dark Mode for Outlook in macOS?

Tags: outlook, macos-darkmode

With the latest update of Microsoft Outlook for Mac (Version 16.20), I activated Dark Mode but, now that I've been using it for a while, I find it difficult to read my mails.

How can I switch back to normal mode? I didn't find an option to disable the dark mode in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a command line, type:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

Credits: [Is there a way to toggle Dark Mode on/off for individual apps in MacOs Mojave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562383/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-dark-mode-on-off-for-individual-apps-in-macos-mojave)