# Turn off Dark Mode only for Safari in macOS Big Sur 11.6

Tags: macos, safari, macos-big-sur, darkmode

The solutions provided in these related questions

1. [Is there a way to toggle Dark Mode on/off for individual apps in MacOs Mojave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562383/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-dark-mode-on-off-for-individual-apps-in-macos-mojave)
2. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338044/can-i-turn-to-dark-mode-only-for-specific-apps-in-macos-mojave
3. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346579/how-can-i-remove-dark-mode-from-ms-office-apps-without-disabling-it-across-mac

do not work with the most recent update of MacOS. Specifically, the line

```
defaults write <Bundle-Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes
```

does not have any effect in Safari. Neither does the app NightOwl, though it does work for apps other than Safari.

Does anyone have any suggestions on why this no longer works?

Comment: Not sure but I use Gray by zenangst and it works pretty good

Comment: It works for me. <Bundle-Identifier> - have you replaced this? I am on 11.6 + Safari 14

Comment: @MarekH I replaced it with com.apple.Safari and was only able to get dark Safari when the theme was light. I couldn't do the reverse

Comment: @Osian Awesome! That did exactly what I wanted. If you submit that as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @rosalynnas Sure done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Gray](https://github.com/zenangst/Gray), which is available on GitHub. It will do what you want to do.